# How to make a literal copy of a function in C/C++ (Windows)?

Tags: c++, c, function, hook, function-pointers

I was thinking if there's any way to, literally, copy a function. For example, if I have a funcion `foo()` that outputs "Hello world!", I want to copy that behaviour into a new function `bar()`. If I simply do `bar = &foo`, then If `foo()` changes at runtime, `bar()` will change too (because it's just a pointer). Maybe `CopyMemory()` can help me?

I say "change at runtime" because my code Hooks `foo()` and replaces it with another function, let's call it `fooReplaced()`; so If now I call `foo()`, `fooReplaced()` will be called instead. So I need to keep a reference to the original function, that's why I need to copy `foo()` to `bar()` before hooking.

**I think now it's very clear what I mean when saying "change at runtime", don't know why this question is "[on hold]"**

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why bother duplicating code?  I don't understand.

Comment: What's the point? What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: Ctrl+C then Ctrl+V surely help you..

Comment: What do you mean by function "changing at runtime"? Functions are not supposed to change unless you have JIT or something.

Comment: Copying binary code is pointless. Copying source code is just bad (and one of the major offenses a programmer can commit).

Comment: Edited to be more specific!! Obviously I can't do Ctrl+C then Ctrl+V.

Comment: @DietmarKühl: It is far from "pointless".  Certainly not the technique I would ever reach for first, but code injection, hot-patching, and hooking all have their uses.  Not all malicious either.

Comment: When you say "hook", do you mean "function pointers"? How exactly is foo replaced? Is it `void (*myHook)(); myHook = &foo; /*...*/ myHook = &fooReplaced`, and then elsewhere call `myHook()`?

Comment: I you can copy a function with C(++) on windows, it can on any platform, not just windows.

Comment: @Arkadiy Mmm I really don't know, but I'm sure that's not the way, it's much complex. As I said in another comment, I'm using a lib for that, not building my own code. Thanks for the comment.

Comment: A library that can replace a function at runtime probably can copy a function just as well. Ask your library vendor how to do that. (I am not resoonsible for any personal injury and liss of ptlroperty that is likely to result).

Comment: What do you pass to your library to set the hook to a particular function? Also, is the library the only thing that calls the function?

Comment: Well, I pass foo() and replacedFoo(). @n.m. please check out this comment (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20686777/how-to-copy-a-function-in-c-c-windows#comment30980322_20687069)!

Comment: Hold on, this is strange. `libraryFunction(foo())` would receive the result of foo(), not any sort of reference to foo. Also, is the foo() called by the library? Is it called only by library and not by anything else?

Comment: The function is called like this: `libraryFunction(&foo, &replacedFoo);`

Comment: All of the techniques that @BenVoigt mentions are real and have applications, but they *require* that the programmer knows *precisely* what they want to accomplish and understands the way the target platform works at a very low level. Much more detail is needed for this question to be well defined.

Comment: I just read the thread. I'm afraid the short answer is "You can't". But how about adding a few lines of fantasy code? (does not work, but shows what it would like if it existed). Also add to your question why the method for hot patching `foo()` at runtime can't be used on `bar()`, like this `libraryFunction(&bar, &foo)` (getting the *new* foo).

Comment: Hi @ixe013, thanks for your comment. I tried `libraryFunction(&bar, &foo)` to "unhook", but it seems that the function enters on a infinte loop :-\. Any other ideas? Thanks again.

Comment: A mistake: after "unhooking", when `foo()` is called it enters on an infinte loop, not the `libraryFunction()` function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Interesting question!

The answer is 'possibly', but you'll need to be aware of any number of fine-detail issues with the compiler/platform.

First, if you want to make a copy of an entire function in memory, you need two things:-

a: You must have 'read-access' to your executable code. Most OSes prevent this via DEP or something similar.

b: You must be able to determine where in memory your function is. You know the entry point (`&foo`) but can you guarantee that the compiler/linker/loader doesn't scatter it around, or rearrange (== optimise) it so that a common tail section is replaced with a JMP to another piece of code?

Assuming that the code is contiguous, how to find the end? Interpret the machine code instructions, looking for a RET, maybe - or look at the symbol table to determine the address of the next following function. Either could work, but both may have flaws...

Finally, once you've got your copy - can you actually execute it? You have the problem of DEP again, but you also have the problem that the binary code may not be position-independent. Instead of saying `JMP to PC + n`, the instructions may have the form `JMP to absolute address N` (where N was an address in the space you copied...)

There's the additional complication of things like `static` data. Do you want your copy of the function to have different static data to the original, if not, then what...?

Summary: it's a nightmare on a number of levels. I'd try and find an alternative approach!

Comment: Thank you very much but I really don't understand anything about Asm. I expect a simple CopyMemory() call hahah lol

Answer (score 2):

Can you not just have bar() call foo()? This way no matter what foo does, bar will do the same

```
void bar() {
    foo();
}
```

You should give more information about *why* you want to do this, as then perhaps we can suggest a way to accomplish it in a sensible way.

EDIT: Ok, now with your edit to indicate you're using hooks that changes things significantly.

I believe that if you wrap as above then bar will have its effects updated along with foo, otherwise when you altered something with a hook at run time there would be no effect.

In order to have a function that retains the original form of foo, could you set it up like so

```
void unchangedFoo() {
    //...
}

void foo() {
    unchangedFoo();
}
```

and then you hook into foo, but still have the old unchangedFoo() intact?

Comment: Yes, I should have been more specific! Sorry.

Comment: Mmm but when hooking foo() it will be replaced by replacedFoo(), so It won't call unchangedFoo() anymore. And I don't have the code of foo().

Comment: I think I might need a bit of clarification on where foo is currently used and where you do and do not want it to change.  Is there some big volume of library code that calls foo (and you cannot make that call a wrapper to foo...) where you do want it to change, but then you have a place where you also want to be able to call the old version of foo as well as having the new version?

Comment: `foo` belongs to the `p` process. I inject my DLL into `p` and hook `foo`, replacing it with `replacedFoo` (which is inside my DLL). Sorry if I can't understand your idea (I do not speak english very well), but I think I can't call the original funcion that way (as I understand).

Comment: Ok, so you are the library and you're trying to modify the original application... very strange situation.  Is there any way to hook their foo into your dll as fishedFoo, then hook your replacedFoo into the application as foo?

Comment: But, as I understand, when all the functions are hooked `replacedFoo()` will be called when trying to call `foo()`. Once `replacedFoo()` have done it stuff it will call `fishedFoo()`right? This one will attemp to call the original function `foo()` but no way, `foo()` is hooked! It will call again `replacedFoo()` and enter in an infinite loop. Please tell me if I'm wrong or I don't understand that you mean.

Answer (score 2):

It seems that after hooking a function (replacing its implementation with your own), you want the ability to call the original.  Much like a subclass calling the base class version of a method the subclass overrode.  The rest of my answer is based on this assumed understanding...

This capability should be provided by your hooking technique.  Generally the function is left intact except for a couple instructions in the preamble being overwritten by a jump.

Another common assumption, almost universally true, is that the body of the function doesn't contain any backward branches into the preamble.

So running the original consists of executing the instructions that were overwritten (the hook procedure should have saved these if for no other reason than to put them back during hook removal) and then branching to the remainder of the function.

This can't be done using C++ function pointers, or in fact using portable code at all.  It is highly instruction set dependent, since it's necessary to discriminate instruction boundaries, which is very easy on some architectures (that have fixed instruction size), but on other widely used platforms (Intel x86 and derivatives, for example) it is non-trivial.

Because the remainder of the function body exists at the original location, relative jumps, even into other functions, remain valid.  Only relative addressing in the preamble would have to be adjusted.  And normally the preamble is just a few `PUSH` instructions to save registers.

Comment: Thanks. I'm not very familiar with function hooking, just using a lib that does that for me. The problem is that it doesn't work at the moment to retrieve the original function!

Comment: Well this is a capability that your library should be providing for you.  Which library is it?

Comment: Yes you're right... but I think the lib's owner doesn't support it anymore. The lib isn't on the net, it's just called "Hook.dll".

Comment: @cdonts lets clarify something first, the function you want to hook belongs in the application itself or its being invoked from a external library (.dll) ?

Comment: The target function belongs to another process in which I inject a Dll

Answer (score 0):

I'm not all to great in C++ so this may be wrong.

Couldn't you just do:

```
int function(){
    otherFunction();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Functions generally should not change at runtime, at least not in C/C++.

Perhaps you need to rethink the way you are approaching the task at hand.

FYI: Without more details on exactly *why* you are copying this code, or *how* the functions might change, you will probably not receive an answer that you like.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand it you want to hook a function and be able to call the original.

There's nothing like that in C++.

However, for a given platform you can use platform specific functionality. E.g. in Windows you can use **[Microsoft Detours](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/projects/detours/)**.

Comment: Ok thanks for your answer, but doest Microsoft Detours works with non-API functions? I mean, the target function has nothing to do with the Windows API or something related to Microsoft.

Comment: I think it also works with non-API functions, yes. There's nothing special about API functions, so such a limitation would have to be put explicitly in there. Disclaimer: I've only toy-tested it, then with the API functions I wanted to hook.

Comment: It might only work (or work best) with `__stdcall` functions, since all the WinAPI functions are.

Comment: Ok thanks for your answer again. But I'll have to remove all my old code and start from the beginning...

Answer (score 0):

In C / C++ `foo` is by definition a pointer, a pointer to the function `foo()`. Theoretically, and of course depending on how the code was written, `foo` can be changed to another address at run time, invoking another function when `foo()` is called, but the original machine code of `foo` should remain untouched in the same memory space and address.

In a matter of fact, trying to change code at run time is not only a stupid thing to do but will also raise a segmentation fault exception as you are trying to write to code area.

Even if you knew the size of `foo` in memory after compiled, what is highly compiler and platform specific, it would probably not work if you copy it to another address because of [absolute and relative addressing mismatches](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Addressing_mode#Simple_addressing_modes_for_code), so it's completely out of question.

Comment: Hooking involves making the code area writable...

Comment: Yes, but you have to make the necessary syscalls to make the system give you the permission to do so. And usually hooking is made in the externals tables, not in the functions directly. The functions machine code is a very messy thing that may be highly optimized. Thats when messing with the machine code, as done by cracks (piracy), the crack is done to deal with specific builds of the project.

Comment: Well yes, hooking libraries make syscalls.